# JetBrains Rider refactor exclude path from scanning

Tags: c#, rider

Is there a way to exclude directories from scanning when using refactor or find usages etc?
I've got a number of migrations in my app and every time I want to rename a property Rider starts scanning migrations folder which takes ~30s to be performed.

Comment: Something similar is here https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000019480-Exclude-js-build-files-from-search-results but it didn't work for me. There are still 2 opened tickets which should probably resolve this but they are still in progress

Comment: I'm also trying to find how to do this.

Comment: Same for me. Rider is scanning some dotnet libs for renaming...